# Is it possible to use a 3rd party commenting service like the facebook comments api or disqus on a client side only app?

Tags: facebook, comments, disqus

If so, how?  Any details or references would be helpful in getting me pointed in the right direction.  I've been doing a lot of research on the subject and I'm hitting a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible as Facebook Comments & Disqus are client side by nature. They're pretty much javascript code that you paste into your HTML page.

Take a look at this page for information on implementing disqus:

http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/

Here's a guide on implementing FB comments on your site:

http://maketecheasier.com/add-facebook-comment-system-to-site/2011/03/10

Comment: Don't they verify the site the request is coming from though?

Comment: They verify what domain your HTML page is being served from, not the client (user/request) browsing it.

Comment: I think here is where I'm getting confused.  My HTML page isn't being served from any domain if the HTML is stored on my (the users) local machine, right?  This is a chrome app that is downloaded once by the user and the html and javascript is then "permanently" stored on the users machine.  Maybe my original question wasn't explained well enough?

Comment: What kind of chrome app is it? A hosted app or a packaged app? If it's a hosted app, it will be the same as a regular web page, but I don't think it will work for a packaged app. The comment systems need a reference url to work properly.

Comment: It's a packaged app.  Bummer.